# Cannot start h2o

Tags: r, h2o

As the title says. I cannot run `h20.init`.

I have already downloaded the 64 bit version of the [Java SE Development Kit 8u291](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase-jdk8-downloads.html). I also downloaded the xgboost library in R (`install.packages("xgboost")` ). Finally, I have updated all my NVIDIA drivers and downloaded the latest CUDA (although, tbh I don't even know what that does). I followed the steps described [in the NVIDIA forums](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/windows-10-cuda-installation-failure-solved/64389) to avoid the crash I had when installing (i.e. remove integration with visual studio). FWIW I'm using a [DELL Inspiron 15 Gaming](https://www.dell.com/us/dfh/p/inspiron-15-5577-gaming-laptop/pd) and it has a NVIDIA GTX 1050 with 4GB.

Here's the full code I'm using (straight from the [h2o download instructions](https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/downloading.html) except for the first line):

```
library(xgboost)
library(h2o)
localH2O = h2o.init()
demo(h2o.kmeans)
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

The full message I get when running the above code chunk:

```
H2O is not running yet, starting it now...

Note:  In case of errors look at the following log files:
    C:\Users\<my username>\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpcdvCce\file1a106074110b/h2o_<my username>_started_from_r.out
    C:\Users\<my username>\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpcdvCce\file1a10253139db/h2o_<my username>_started_from_r.err

java version "15.0.2" 2021-01-19
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 15.0.2+7-27)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 15.0.2+7-27, mixed mode, sharing)

Starting H2O JVM and connecting: ............................................................Diagnostic HTTP Request:
   HTTP Status Code: -1
HTTP Error Message: Failed to connect to localhost port 54321: Connection refused
Cannot load library from path lib/windows_64/xgboost4j_gpu.dll
Cannot load library from path lib/xgboost4j_gpu.dll
Failed to load library from both native path and jar!
Cannot load library from path lib/windows_64/xgboost4j_omp.dll
Cannot load library from path lib/xgboost4j_omp.dll
Failed to load library from both native path and jar!
Cannot load library from path lib/windows_64/xgboost4j_minimal.dll
Cannot load library from path lib/xgboost4j_minimal.dll
Failed to load library from both native path and jar!
Failed to add native path to the classpath at runtime
java.io.IOException: Failed to get field handle to set library path
    at ai.h2o.xgboost4j.java.NativeLibLoader.addNativeDir(NativeLibLoader.java:229)
    at ai.h2o.xgboost4j.java.NativeLibLoader.initXGBoost(NativeLibLoader.java:43)
    at ai.h2o.xgboost4j.java.NativeLibLoader.getLoader(NativeLibLoader.java:66)
    at hex.tree.xgboost.XGBoostExtension.initXgboost(XGBoostExtension.java:70)
    at hex.tree.xgboost.XGBoostExtension.isEnabled(XGBoostExtension.java:51)
    at water.ExtensionManager.isEnabled(ExtensionManager.java:189)
    at water.ExtensionManager.registerCoreExtensions(ExtensionManager.java:103)
    at water.H2O.main(H2O.java:2203)
    at water.H2OStarter.start(H2OStarter.java:22)
    at water.H2OStarter.start(H2OStarter.java:48)
    at water.H2OApp.main(H2OApp.java:12)
Cannot initialize XGBoost backend! Xgboost (enabled GPUs) needs: 
  - CUDA 8.0
XGboost (minimal version) needs: 
  - GCC 4.7+
For more details, run in debug mode: `java -Dlog4j.configuration=file:///tmp/log4j.properties -jar h2o.jar`


ERROR: Unknown argument (<my username>/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpcdvCce)


Usage:  java [-Xmx<size>] -jar h2o.jar [options]
        (Note that every option has a default and is optional.)

    -h | -help
          Print this help.

    -version
          Print version info and exit.

    -name <h2oCloudName>
          Cloud name used for discovery of other nodes.
          Nodes with the same cloud name will form an H2O cloud
          (also known as an H2O cluster).

    -flatfile <flatFileName>
          Configuration file explicitly listing H2O cloud node members.

    -ip <ipAddressOfNode>
          IP address of this node.

    -port <port>
          Port number for this node (note: port+1 is also used by default).
          (The default port is 54321.)

    -network <IPv4network1Specification>[,<IPv4network2Specification> ...]
          The IP address discovery code will bind to the first interface
          that matches one of the networks in the comma-separated list.
          Use instead of -ip when a broad range of addresses is legal.
          (Example network specification: '10.1.2.0/24' allows 256 legal
          possibilities.)

    -ice_root <fileSystemPath>
          The directory where H2O spills temporary data to disk.

    -log_dir <fileSystemPath>
          The directory where H2O writes logs to disk.
          (This usually has a good default that you need not change.)

    -log_level <TRACE,DEBUG,INFO,WARN,ERRR,FATAL>
          Write messages at this logging level, or above.  Default is INFO.

    -max_log_file_size
          Maximum size of INFO and DEBUG log files. The file is rolled over after a specified size has been reached.
          (The default is 3MB. Minimum is 1MB and maximum is 99999MB)

    -flow_dir <server side directory or HDFS directory>
          The directory where H2O stores saved flows.
          (The default is 'C:\Users\<my username>\h2oflows'.)

    -nthreads <#threads>
          Maximum number of threads in the low priority batch-work queue.
          (The default is.)

    -client
          Launch H2O node in client mode.

    -notify_local <fileSystemPath>
          Specifies a file to write when the node is up. The file contains one line with the IP and
          port of the embedded web server. e.g. 192.168.1.100:54321

    -context_path <context_path>
          The context path for jetty.

Authentication options:

    -jks <filename>
          Java keystore file

    -jks_pass <password>
          (Default is 'h2oh2o')

    -jks_alias <alias>
          (Optional, use if the keystore has multiple certificates and you want to use a specific one.)

    -hostname_as_jks_alias
          (Optional, use if you want to use the machine hostname as your certificate alias.)

    -hash_login
          Use Jetty HashLoginService

    -ldap_login
          Use Jetty Ldap login module

    -kerberos_login
          Use Jetty Kerberos login module

    -spnego_login
          Use Jetty SPNEGO login service

    -pam_login
          Use Jetty PAM login module

    -login_conf <filename>
          LoginService configuration file

    -spnego_properties <filename>
          SPNEGO login module configuration file

    -form_auth
          Enables Form-based authentication for Flow (default is Basic authentication)

    -session_timeout <minutes>
          Specifies the number of minutes that a session can remain idle before the server invalidates
          the session and requests a new login. Requires '-form_auth'. Default is no timeout

    -internal_security_conf <filename>
          Path (absolute or relative) to a file containing all internal security related configurations

Cloud formation behavior:

    New H2O nodes join together to form a cloud at startup time.
    Once a cloud is given work to perform, it locks out new members
    from joining.

Examples:

    Start an H2O node with 4GB of memory and a default cloud name:
        $ java -Xmx4g -jar h2o.jar

    Start an H2O node with 6GB of memory and a specify the cloud name:
        $ java -Xmx6g -jar h2o.jar -name MyCloud

    Start an H2O cloud with three 2GB nodes and a default cloud name:
        $ java -Xmx2g -jar h2o.jar &
        $ java -Xmx2g -jar h2o.jar &
        $ java -Xmx2g -jar h2o.jar &
```

Comment: To narrow it down, does H2O work if you exclude the `library(xgboost)` line? The "port 54321: Connection refused" could indicate you have a firewall blocking access (or you might have had a popup asking permission?). The rest sounds like java cannot find the gpu libraries. (I.e. you may have two problems interacting here...)

Comment: P.S. Referencing https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/downloading.html, did you start the h2o jar with no problems? And could view Flow in your browser? Make sure you keep the jar running in the background, as that is what your R script will be connecting to.

Comment: @DarrenCook Thanks! No, it doesn't run even without that line. And no, I don't have a firewall. Any good solution to the java-gpu library problem?

Comment: Also,  no... I could never make it work. I don't know how to start the jar file - I only use R and I have not tried anywhere else.

Comment: Troubleshoot the normal H2O install first. The instructions for how to start the jar file are in the docs page you linked to. If that doesn't work, hopefully the error messages help?  By "I don't have a firewall", do you mean you have explicitly turned off the Windows firewall; I think it is always running by default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... after a lot of poking around I found the answer. Windows Defender ughhh was blocking access to the h2o.jar. The solution was to open PowerShell on the h2o java folder and run the h2o.jar using `java -jar h2o.jar`. Then you'll get the security prompt asking you to authorize the program (I've had to do it every time, so you might want to check your settings). Once you do that `h2o.init()` runs very smoothly in R.